# return a flattened list from a list comprehension of a nested list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a flattened list of all users that belong to a linux group.
The structure returning from `grp.getgrall()` is:

```
[
  grp.struct_group(
                  gr_name='plugdev',
                  gr_passwd='x',
                  gr_gid=46,
                  gr_mem=[
                            'rolf',
                            'public'
                          ])
]
```

where the members of the group are in the form of a list in `gr_mem=[]`

I can use the following:

```
import grp
plugdev_members = []
for group in grp.getgrall():
    if "plugdev" in group.gr_name:
        for user in group.gr_mem:
            plugdev_members.append(user)
```

which returns a flat list:

```
['rolf','public']
```

Using list comprehension:

```
plugdev_members = [
                    mem for mem in [
                                    m.gr_mem for m in grp.getgrall()
                                       if "plugdev" in m.gr_name
                                   ]
                  ] 
or

plugdev_members = [
                    m.gr_mem for m in grp.getgrall() 
                      if "plugdev" in m.gr_name
                   ]
```

I get a list within a list:

```
[['rolf', 'public']]
```

I'm sure that there must be a way to return a flattened list using list comprehension, I'm just not seeing it.  I know that I need a second loop within the first, as per the first example but I'm just not getting it right.
Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a second loop inside the first one:

```
plugdev_members = [m.gr_mem for m in grp.getgrall() if "plugdev" in m.gr_name]
#                  ^----- This is a list, so pugdev_members will be a list of lists
```

Instead:

```
plugdev_members = [x for m in grp.getgrall() for x in m.gr_mem if "plugdev" in m.gr_name]
```

Comment: The old 'inverse the operation' of an equation, switcheroo. I never did crack that! Many thanks, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony That's exactly what was in the duplicated questions linked.

Comment: @PeterWood Ok! Finally got it `x = [item for sublist in grp.getgrall() for item in sublist.gr_mem if "plugdev" in sublist.gr_name]`. Thanks!